# citusdb: psql commands not working

Tags: database, postgresql, citus

I am trying for the first time [citusdb](http://www.citusdata.com/), and in the download page, they put a getting started guide, so I am following it.

First, I am trying this on my local computer, and with the sample data on the third point of the getting started guide [here](http://www.citusdata.com/main-download).

There, they offer a modified `psql` so you can use it with `citusdb`. First I connect with this:

```
/opt/citusdb/2.0/bin/psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres
```

Then, when I try to create a database, the guide says that you can use the reserved word `DISTRIBUTE`, but when I try the command on the guide:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_reviews
(
    customer_id TEXT not null,
    review_date DATE not null,
    review_rating INTEGER not null,
    review_votes INTEGER,
    review_helpful_votes INTEGER,
    product_id CHAR(10) not null,
    product_title TEXT not null,
    product_sales_rank BIGINT,
    product_group TEXT,
    product_category TEXT,
    product_subcategory TEXT,
    similar_product_ids CHAR(10)[]
)
DISTRIBUTE BY APPEND (review_date);
```

It seems that the `psql` is not accepting the `DISTRIBUTE` word, because it shows an `syntax error at or near DISTRIBUTE`

Please help if someone has used this, and knows what the problem is, maybe it is too obvious, but it is my first time with `citusdb`.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, someone with the required reputation, create the `citusdb` tag, and update the post.

Comment: @eLRuLL are you sure that citusdb instance is running and you are not connected to standard postgres instance? Please check with ps aux | grep post , and you should see /opt/citusdb/2.0/bin/postgres in this list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you're connecting to a normal PostgreSQL instance, not their hacked-up PostgreSQL. Try `select version()` to confirm that.

Perhaps you're running CitusDB on a different port, like 5433?

Comment: I was running `sudo -u postgres /opt/citusdb/2.0/bin/pg_ctl -D /opt/citusdb/2.0/data -l logfile start`, but I first needed to stop my default postgres service. It seems that if postgres is running it just leave it there, not showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are running the citus provided psql, which is provided in /opt